# Remove Fields when query at sails js

Tags: sails.js

i have a question. How can i solve to remove field packet when i query in sails js? [OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Sq9w.png)This is my code[CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/437p1.png)

Answer (score 1):

sendNativeQuery will return object with 2 properties, rows (data) and fields (selected fields). Use `return res.json(result.rows)`